# ¿Qué debo poner en la pantalla de inicio de mi aplicación iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

La pantalla de inicio que viene al crear un nuevo proyecto para iOS (LaunchScreen.storyboard) solo trae unas etiquetas con el nombre de la aplicación y del desarrollador. Si uso Main.storyboard como pantalla de inicio, la aplicación arranca con la pantalla en negro, para luego si cargar la interface principal.

¿Qué tipo de controles debo poner entonces en LaunchScreen.storyboard? Si cualquier tipo de control me sirve, ¿porqué entonces no puedo usar Main.storyboard?

Lo que no quiero es tener que mantener una copia de la interface principal pero sin Custom Class en los controles, para poder usarla como pantalla de inicio.

Answer (score 8):

En la sección *General* de tu proyecto en **Xcode** ve a *App Icons and Launch Images* para cambiar la opción *Launch Screen File* y elegir `Main.storyboard`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El splash screen es muy útil para agregar una presentación a tu aplicación, ese es todo el objetivo. Pero le da a tu aplicación un tiempo adicional de inicio en el que puede cargar assets u otro tipo de información desde Internet sin dañar la experiencia de usuario haciendo que este espere un tiempo determinado sin recibir un output visual por parte de la aplicación.

Answer (score 4):

Como su nombre lo dice "Launch Screen" se usa para mostrar algo en pantalla mientras el Main.Storyboard se carga.

Al Sistema Operativo le toma unos segundos cargar tu aplicación y para esto te permite usar el LaunchScreen.storyboard para mostrar algo en ese lapso. (Antes se utilizaba una imagen con el nombre de SplashScreen.png.

Ahora, tu tienes el control de cuando pasar del Launch Screen al Main así que puedes poner usar una imagen o un video almacenados localmente en la aplicación mientras que el Sistema Operativo OS carga el Main.storyboard pero tu puedes aprovechar y cargar cualquier otro dato, validar si hay un update, cargar perfil de usuario, descargar imágenes, etc mientras el Launch Screen muestra el video o un Activity Indicator y al terminar de obtener todo lo que necesites ahora sí mostrar el Main.Storyboard.

Obvio, no abuses ya que el usuario no tiene mucha paciencia, y no olvides mostrar algún tipo de retroalimentación al usuario para que no piense que la aplicación se quedo trabada como desplegar mensajes que indiquen que "se está descargando información", "obteniendo permisos", o algún indicador de progreso con el porcentaje de descarga, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hace 5 años hubo una larga discusión sobre si los splash screen eran necesarios o hacían que la inicialización se sintiera más lenta. Muchos postularon que era mejor poner una captura de cómo se vería la aplicación ya cargada dando al usuario la sensación que ya estaba en memoria. Hoy en día se están volviendo a utilizar bajo el argumento de que el splash debe demostrar el espíritu de la app.

Recuerda que el splash está en la caché del springboard por lo tanto tiene algunas limitaciones técnicas. Por ejemplo, al momento de escribir este texto no es posible asignar una clase al view controller y por lo tanto no puedes ejecutar código. Mas bien puedes poner imágenes, textos, logos y por supuesto usar el autolayout.

Comment: tienes algo que corrobore esto??